# markerclusterer mouseover doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, mouseover, markerclusterer

I just looked at the following post: [markerclusterer info windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642728/markerclusterer-info-windows)

There's a thing I need in this post, the mouseover event for the markerclusterer. I need to change the icon when the mouse is hovered over the icon.

I got the following code:

```
var clusterOptions = {
    zoomOnClick: false,
    styles: [{
        url: 'images/template/cluster.png',
        height: 68, 
        width: 57,
        textColor: '#FFF'
    }]
}
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, "mouseover", function(cluster) {
    console.log('test');
});

// Listen for a cluster to be clicked
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {

    var markers = cluster.getMarkers();
    var content = '';
    $.each(markers, function () {
        content += this.get('content');
    });

    // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
    var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
    info.set('position', cluster.center_);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map, info);

});
```

The clusterer works fine and also the infowindow shows up nice. It combines all the infowindows from the markers in the cluster.

What am I doing wrong in the mouseover event? I don't even see the console.log!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I just resolved the issue, i'll post the answer when I can, but have to wait because I don't have enough reputationpoints to answer it straight away :)

Comment: can you tell something more now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was using [markerclustererplus](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus) rather than markerclusterer.
Just replace your script `src`.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/examples/events_example.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following library:

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus

it has mouseover handlers
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html