# Google map API markerclusterer cluster hover event

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have used Google map API v.3 attached with markerclusterer.js.

Is it possible to add a listener to markerclusters created so that it shows an infowindow when hovered on?

I have tried:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'mouseover', (cluster:any) =>{
       console.log("worked"); // here I want to place display some infowindow

       })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [markerclusterer info windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642728/markerclusterer-info-windows)

Comment: @MrUpsidown That particular question involves the usage of the library markerclustererplus , which is not the one I am using.