# Creating Popup box for MarkerClusterer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using MarkerClusterer V3 to reduce the number of markers drawn on the map. Every marker will popup a infobox when clicked (already implemented). What I am trying to achieve is to enable the marker cluster to popup a list of all the infobox associated with the markers that are grouped by that marker cluster.

**Problem:** How can I achieve this? Currently I have an array `markers` that contains all the `google.maps.Marker` pushed into it after creation. `markerclusterer.getMarkers()` can provide me with the lat & lng of the markers in the cluster. I am kind of stuck at this step. Any help really appreciated!

**Example**

[image]

Comment: Have you figured our how to do this yet? I'm trying to do the exact same thing at the moment, I'll let you know if I find anything...

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997070/google-maps-api-v3-infobubble-in-markerclusterer)! If I understood you correctly. I think it will help you.